# Extend a class to use child private variable

Tags: php

I have a class in a vendor folder which have an array

```
private $mids = [
    'a' =>'b',
    'c' => 'd'
];
private $config = [
    'sid' => null,
    'aid' => null,
];
```

and a constructor which sets up private $config

```
function __construct($config){
    foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $this->config)) {
            $this->config[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to update $mid with a new key/value 'x' => 'y' so i extended the class and copied the parent constructor
to child constructor.

But when i try to call the functions which are defined in the parent i get the error that undefined $this->config($key).
so the function is using the parent $config property instead of childs.

What am i doing wrong?

Or what is the best way to do this instead of editing the vendor source

Comment: You could use 'protected' instead of 'private' see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php (but there are many other ways to solve this).

Comment: You cannot use `private` value outside of its class so you must use `protected` instead of using `private` keyword.

Comment: private member are not visible inherited.

Comment: so cannot do anything other than to copy the whole source from vendor code ??

Comment: Might be the same type of question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961907/how-to-call-super-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call super in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961907/how-to-call-super-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Make your variable protected instead of private if you want to use them in your child class .

```
protected $mids = [
'a' =>'b',
'c' => 'd'
 ];
protected $config = [
  'sid' => null,
  'aid' => null,
];
```

Comment: I understand, but i don't want to edit vendor source. 
Is there no other way other than to copy the whole code and modify?

Comment: You can check this it will help you [private-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827101/php-private-variable-access-from-child)

Comment: I assume, that vendor source is available at GitHub or something. You could fork the project and change the code to your needs. You could then even make a merge request to get your changes into the library you're using. In case the merge request will be accepted you are totally out of trouble. Otherwise you just change the dependency to your forked sources. You have to take care of updates of the original sources, though.

Comment: already requested the vendor to update his source, for now i will duplicate the code and use it.